# How can I add user profile support to a google app engine app?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-profiles

I have a Google App Engine app based on django / django_appengine that I wish to modify by adding user profile support to it, because the basic user model is a bit simplistic for my situation.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model called for example `UserProfile` which has as its key a user's email address or user ID.

`UserProfile profile = UserProfile.get_or_create(user.user_id)` will make sure that no user profiles are created for existing user IDs.

Comment: user.user_id only exists for google accounts, it won't work for OpenID accounts

Comment: You can use email then, or maybe key of the `User` you get from `get_current_user()`